# One database, multiple names in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have an old ERP, which handled many organizations in a single db with a suffix on the tables. Lets say the db name is ORG and the tables look like `CLIENTS01`, `CLIENTS02`, `CLIENTS03`.

The new ERP connects to one database per organization.

The sad thing is I need to use both ERPs, so I need to replicate **SAME DB WITH MULTIPLE NAMES**: `ORG01, ORG02, ORG03`.

I was thinking for mirroring but this will increase database workload.
I looked for aliases but didn't find the way to make it work on the same instance.

I tried to create new database and then attach same file MDF file without success.

What would be the simplest way to just create 3 new databases connecting to the same database (1 database, multiple names)?

Comment: These, if I am honest, both sound like a terrible ideas. Why not use a single database, with single tables, and Row Level Security to ensure data can't be accessed via other companies. You can't, however, have both; that sir is a recipe of disaster.

Comment: @Larnu It's actually not a terrible idea. Imagine you provide SaaS to different customers and you don't want a customer affect other customers badly. If you store data of all customers into single database, that's what happens. 

For Carlos, I am afraid, an answer to your question is a topic of data warehouse. I've never heard of more than one dbs connecting to the same data source. You should consider planning a data warehouse.

Comment: @Larnu Agreed, it's quite normal to have a DB per sutomer, means you can move them about and do backups etc without too much interference. The terrible idea is obviously the naming system

Comment: Yes, perhaps I wasn't specific enough about what I felt was "terrible". Separate databases is a very common solution; provided you don't need to try to query all the data in one attempt. Separate tables, less so ideal and likely means dynamic SQL solutions (yuck). At least with separate databases you can parametrise the connection string to connect to the right database.

Comment: You can do it with view that have table with a name in three parts : db_name.schema_name.obect_name

Comment: _What would be the simplest way to just create 3 new dbs connecting to the same db_ No one can really answer this because it (and your goal) are difficult to understand without context. Are you really trying to replicate data between your old and new schemas on a client basis? Or are you trying to migrate? Something else?  And quite frankly - forget about "simple" and focus on "workable".